# Tag badges are indistinguishable from normal badges

Tags: bug, design

On other SE sites, tag badges usually have a distinct look, they don't look identical to the other badges, see Gaming.SE as an example here:

[image]

Here on Skeptics, they look identical:

[image]

The tag badges style should probably be changed to something distinct from the other badges, as on other sites.